# Some operations on large tables on dNFS Clone failing with ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is a though one, with many variables, so bear with me.

I have created two databases using Oracle dNFS clone. The backup image is stored on ASM and both clones are stored on NFS and use the same backup image. It's a plain simple single instance configuration with ASM, no RAC or RAC OneNode.

It s a setup I've always made with no major issues, until now. The only major difference between my previous setups and now is that NFS is configured in a loop, pointing to an export inside the own database machine. I know it's ugly, but I don't have a storage with sharing options available this time and no spare machine to work as NFS server either :(

On many operations on some large tables (`CREATE INDEX` or `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` or even and `UPDATE` statement), I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel
Process ID: 26928
Session ID: 951 Serial number: 25
```

The error is NOT consistent. Some times I try to create a large 'temporary' table to do some tests and it works... some time it doesn't. Creating indexes on big tables always trigger the error. `UPDATES` may or may not trigger the error.

The database instance alert.log shows me:

```
ERROR: unrecoverable error ORA-15310 raised in ASM I/O path; terminating process 8111
```

The ASM alert.log shows nothing. Really, I'm not omitting anything I deem useless, it really shows nothing at the moment the error occurs.

I've used the clone method explained in the link bellow, just adding a few changes to clone.pl to be able to use backup image stored on ASM (and some other more to make it more... hmm... automatic).

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/clonedb-11gr2.php

Anyways, the actual perl script doesn't really matter, it's the SQL generated scripts that do matter.

crtdb.sql looks like this

```
SET ECHO ON
SET FEEDBACK 1
SET NUMWIDTH 10
SET LINESIZE 80
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
SET TAB OFF
SET PAGESIZE 100

STARTUP NOMOUNT PFILE=/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/initSIGEPSQ2.ora
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE SET DATABASE SIGEPSQ2 RESETLOGS
    MAXLOGFILES 32
    MAXLOGMEMBERS 2
    MAXINSTANCES 1
    MAXLOGHISTORY 908
    MAXDATAFILES 300
LOGFILE
  GROUP 1 '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/onlinelog/SIGEPSQ2_log1.log' SIZE 100M BLOCKSIZE 512,
  GROUP 2 '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/onlinelog/SIGEPSQ2_log2.log' SIZE 100M BLOCKSIZE 512
DATAFILE
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/ANALISTA.343.856398795',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/SYSAUX.339.856398619',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/SYSTEM.340.856398765',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TOOLS.342.856398793',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_AUDITSIS.341.856398767',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIDATA01.328.856396117',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIDATA01.329.856396853',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIDATA01.330.856396887',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIDATA01.337.856398299',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.332.856397587',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.333.856397587',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.334.856397663',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.335.856398189',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.336.856398213',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.308.856390947',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.309.856391053',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.310.856391199',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.311.856391783',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.312.856391949',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.313.856391993',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.314.856392609',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.315.856392793',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.316.856392819',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.317.856393455',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.318.856393629',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.319.856393665',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.320.856394309',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.321.856394465',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.322.856394479',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.323.856395185',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.324.856395291',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.273.856380501',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.274.856380517',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.275.856381351',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.296.856387511',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.300.856388377',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.325.856395291',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.326.856396067',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.327.856396091',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.270.856379625',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.272.856380501',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.276.856381367',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.277.856381451',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.298.856387611',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.306.856390167',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.269.856379625',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.279.856382263',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.280.856382327',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.281.856383103',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.282.856383147',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.283.856383203',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.284.856383989',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.285.856384043',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.286.856384047',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.287.856384891',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.297.856387527',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.299.856388377',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.304.856389427',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.288.856384891',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.289.856384937',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.292.856385801',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.293.856386655',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.295.856386685',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.301.856388551',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.302.856389207',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.305.856390073',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.271.856379625',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.278.856382217',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.290.856385781',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.291.856385785',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.294.856386671',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.303.856389273',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.307.856390323',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/UNDOTBS1.331.856396903',
'+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/UNDOTBS1.338.856398573'
CHARACTER SET WE8DEC;
```

dbren.sql looks like this:

```
declare
begin
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/ANALISTA.343.856398795' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ20.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/SYSAUX.339.856398619' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ21.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/SYSTEM.340.856398765' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ22.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TOOLS.342.856398793' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ23.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_AUDITSIS.341.856398767' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ24.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIDATA01.328.856396117' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ25.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIDATA01.329.856396853' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ26.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIDATA01.330.856396887' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ27.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIDATA01.337.856398299' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ28.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.332.856397587' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ29.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.333.856397587' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ210.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.334.856397663' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ211.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.335.856398189' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ212.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_PCIINDEX01.336.856398213' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ213.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.308.856390947' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ214.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.309.856391053' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ215.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.310.856391199' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ216.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.311.856391783' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ217.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.312.856391949' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ218.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.313.856391993' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ219.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.314.856392609' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ220.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.315.856392793' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ221.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.316.856392819' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ222.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.317.856393455' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ223.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.318.856393629' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ224.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.319.856393665' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ225.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.320.856394309' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ226.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.321.856394465' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ227.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.322.856394479' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ228.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.323.856395185' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ229.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA01.324.856395291' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ230.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.273.856380501' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ231.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.274.856380517' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ232.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.275.856381351' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ233.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.296.856387511' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ234.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.300.856388377' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ235.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.325.856395291' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ236.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.326.856396067' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ237.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA02.327.856396091' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ238.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.270.856379625' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ239.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.272.856380501' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ240.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.276.856381367' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ241.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.277.856381451' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ242.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.298.856387611' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ243.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSDATA03.306.856390167' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ244.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.269.856379625' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ245.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.279.856382263' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ246.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.280.856382327' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ247.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.281.856383103' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ248.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.282.856383147' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ249.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.283.856383203' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ250.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.284.856383989' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ251.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.285.856384043' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ252.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.286.856384047' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ253.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.287.856384891' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ254.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.297.856387527' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ255.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.299.856388377' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ256.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX01.304.856389427' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ257.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.288.856384891' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ258.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.289.856384937' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ259.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.292.856385801' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ260.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.293.856386655' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ261.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.295.856386685' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ262.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.301.856388551' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ263.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.302.856389207' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ264.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX02.305.856390073' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ265.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.271.856379625' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ266.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.278.856382217' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ267.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.290.856385781' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ268.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.291.856385785' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ269.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.294.856386671' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ270.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.303.856389273' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ271.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/TS_SIGEPSINDEX03.307.856390323' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ272.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/UNDOTBS1.331.856396903' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ273.dbf');
dbms_dnfs.clonedb_renamefile('+DATA_SIGEPSQA/sigepsqa/datafile/UNDOTBS1.338.856398573' , '/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/datafile/ora_data_SIGEPSQ274.dbf');
end;
/
show errors;
alter database open resetlogs;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP2;
ALTER DATABASE DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP2;
DROP TABLESPACE TEMP;
ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP2 RENAME TO TEMP;
```

Finally init.ora looks like this:

```
*.aq_tm_processes=3
*.audit_file_dest='/oracle/admin/sigepsq2/adump'
*.audit_trail='NONE'
*.backup_tape_io_slaves=TRUE
*.compatible='11.2.0.0.0'
control_files=/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/SIGEPSQ2_ctl.dbf
*.cursor_sharing='FORCE'
*.db_block_size=8192

db_name=SIGEPSQ2

*.dispatchers='(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=sigepsqaXDB)'
*.fast_start_mttr_target=300

*.job_queue_processes=100

*.log_archive_format='ora9_%t_%s_%r.arc'
*.log_archive_max_processes=10
*.log_checkpoint_timeout=0
*.nls_territory='BRAZIL'
*.open_cursors=1000
*.open_links=10
*.open_links_per_instance=10
*.optimizer_index_caching=70
*.optimizer_index_cost_adj=10
*.pga_aggregate_target=5G
*.processes=2500
*.query_rewrite_enabled='TRUE'
*.recyclebin='OFF'
*.remote_login_passwordfile='EXCLUSIVE'
*.resource_limit=TRUE
*.sec_case_sensitive_logon=FALSE

*.sga_target=5G
*.undo_retention=16000
*.undo_tablespace='UNDOTBS1'
*.use_large_pages='ONLY'
*.utl_file_dir='*'
db_create_file_dest=/mnt/nfs/oracle
log_archive_dest=/mnt/nfs/oracle/SIGEPSQ2/archivelog
db_create_online_log_dest_1=/mnt/nfs/oracle
clonedb=true
cluster_database=false
_no_recovery_through_resetlogs=TRUE
```

This is the /etc/exports

```
/oradatanfs 10.147.0.8(rw,sync,no_wdelay,insecure,insecure_locks,no_root_squash,anongid=601)
```

This is /etc/fstab

```
10.147.0.8:/oradatanfs /mnt/nfs/oracle nfs noauto,rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,nfsvers=3,timeo=600 0 0
```

This is /etc/mtab

```
10.147.0.8:/oradatanfs /mnt/nfs/oracle nfs rw,bg,hard,nointr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,tcp,nfsvers=3,timeo=600,addr=10.147.0.8 0 0
```

This is /etc/oranfstab

```
server: p08
local: 10.147.0.8
path: 10.147.0.8
dontroute
export: /oradatanfs mount: /mnt/nfs/oracle
```

All permissions on NFS are set to oracle:dba. I've tried chmod'ing everything to 777 or 1777, but the error remained.

I know it's a long post and a very complex and challenging scenario, but can anybody help me on this one? I'm trying to fix it for a couple a days now, but the ORA-15310 error is too generic and there's nothing on MOS to help me out. On top of that, I'm not sure which one, NFS or ASM, is to blame here.

Regards,
Daniel Stolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so you know, I didn't have to open a TAR. Last weekend, I remade the image of the same (remote) production database, using `duplicate from active database`. Before starting the dNFS clone, I opened the image and issued several `alter system archive log current` before closing the database to use it as base image. Then I created the dNFS clone and everything went just fine.

Apparently, there was something wrong with the image after all.